# Why Spring Batch is creating lower case table on MySql on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Batch project (running on Spring Boot) and I am running into a nagging problem.

Basically untill now I used H2 database. In order to go in production (on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine) I am trying to replace it with MySql.

This was my **application.properties** initial configuration (using H2 database):

```
#Database Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:springbatch;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
```

So I replaced these configuration with these new configuration using MySql instead H2:

```
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring
spring.datasource.username=andrea
spring.datasource.password=Aprile_12_Test
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

As you can see the initialization mode is set to **always** so running my Spring Batch application the tables will be created into my **spring** MySql database. Tables are created but they are lowercase (into the used **schema-mysql.sql** file are all uppercase:

```
mysql> show tables;
+------------------------------+
| Tables_in_spring             |
+------------------------------+
| BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION          |
| BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE           |
| DATABASECHANGELOG            |
| DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK        |
| batch_job_execution          |
| batch_job_execution_context  |
| batch_job_execution_params   |
| batch_job_instance           |
| batch_step_execution         |
| batch_step_execution_context |
+------------------------------+
```

It seems to be the cause of some error because then it doesn't create other table using table with uppercase reference.

Why am I facing this problem? What can I do to solve this? Exist a way to specify to use uppercase name as defined into the .sql file?

Comment: Its always a good practice to use lowercase names to make it platform independent. Linux and windows treat them differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself allowing Spring Boot\Batch to create the database table the first time. Into **application.properties**::

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

removing liquidebase library from pom.xml:

```
<!-- 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
-->
```

Finnally disabling database table creation into the **application.properties**:

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never
```

Finnally running the batch. The problems seems to be liquidbase.